# Adding drop-down and radio buttons

Tags: 7, forms

Is there any module that will help me create a `drop-down menu` and `list` as shown in the following picture ?

[image]

I want to connect this with registration page.

Comment: What do you want in drop-down-menu? radio buttons?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan No. They are both separate

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided; see [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There are many form-related modules, there is also Form API. But without detailed informations what are you trying to achieve and what you already tried, we are pretty much clueless and helping you is, quite literally, impossible.

Comment: @SuhailGupta I I understand correctly you want both input formats as one field/wizard?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan yeah.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Please edit your post to make it valid post. (Instead of just providing a screenshot). Otherwise It will be closed as off-topic. I'm going to post an answer hope you will edit your post ASAP.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I am sorry, but what do I add in the edit ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Describe what you want exactly and what you have tried so far and try to elaborate you question a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Double field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module

> Double field is a small module written to provide extensions to Drupal's core Fields. By this module you can split your fields up into two separate parts.
>
> For the moment it includes the following sub-widget types:
>
> - Textfield
> - Select list
> - Single checkbox
> - Textarea
>
> Consequently, in all there are 4 x 4 = 16 widget types.